# EZAudio Plot Mirror Not Consistant

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ezaudio

I implemented the EZAudioPlotGL in about 4 different view controllers. At times only the top part of it is showing , even though shouldMirror is set to YES at all times. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: do you got solution for same question?

Answer (score 0):

I have used "EZAudioPlot.h" class rather than "EZAudioPlotGL.h". which resolves issue of inconsistent wave form and works same as "EZAudioPlotGL.h"

and implemented clear method in "EZAudioPlot.m" class because it does not have implementation or clear method.

```
 -(void)clear
{
    float              empty[_changingHistorySize];
    // Figure out better way to do this
    for(int i = 0; i < _changingHistorySize; i++ )
    {
        empty[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < _scrollHistoryLength; i++)
    {
        _scrollHistory[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    _scrollHistoryIndex = 0;

    [self setSampleData:_scrollHistory
                 length:(!_setMaxLength?kEZAudioPlotMaxHistoryBufferLength:_scrollHistoryLength)];
}
```